# Using R write data frame to hdfs via drill

Tags: r, hdfs

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b) 
ch <- odbcConnect("Drill")
sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "tblTest", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

When I executed the code above, it throws exception:

```
Error in sqlSave(ch, df, tablename = "tblTest", rownames = FALSE, append = FALSE) : 
  HY000 1040 [MapR][Drill] (1040) Drill failed to execute the query: CREATE TABLE "tblTest"  ("n" DOUBLE, "s" varchar(255), "b" varchar(255))
[30024]Query execution error. Details:[ 
ParseException: Encountered "\"" at line 1, column 14.
Was expecting one of:
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...

]
```

I researched quite long on the internet, but still can't find a solution. Is there anyone can help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at `rhdfs` package?
https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs

Comment: I tried rhdfs, but it doesn't work. Because my R server in not in the hadoop cluster. it locates in another machine which outside the Hadoop cluster.

Comment: You should start a HiveServer2 on a machine that has hadoop cluster and then try to connect to this server with dplyr.spark.hive package https://github.com/piccolbo/dplyr.spark.hive